# Сравнение даты с датой из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datetime

Код JavaScript отправляет AJAX запрос в PHP с датой. Как сделать проверку, есть ли такая дата в базе данных? Если есть то все хорошо, если нет то добавляем. Формат даты из кода `"Thu Nov 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT 0500 (RTZ 4 (Зима))"`, а в бд формат даты `"2015-11-26 00:00:00"`

```js
function(start) {
    $(".fc-cell-overlay").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            data: 'postVar=' + start,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("No PHP script: ");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
}
```

это php код здесь я получаю дату и сравниваю ее с базой,но не получается

```
 $id = $_POST['postVar'];
 $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE 'events'=$id");
```

Comment: А что именно у вас не получается сделать? Конвертировать дату из одного формата в другой или сохранить значение в БД? Или вы просто хотите, чтобы все сделали за вас?

Comment: Ну так добавьте в вопрос то, как вы пытаетесь это делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно правильно форматировать дату на клиенте

```
function(start) {
    $(".fc-cell-overlay").click(function(){
        start = new Date(start);
        day = date.getDate().toString();
        if (day.length == 1) day = '0' + day;
        month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
        if (month.length == 1) month = '0' + month;
        year = date.getFullYear();
        var start_str = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            data: 'postVar=' + start_str,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("No PHP script: ");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
}
```

*а если часто нужно форматировать дату есть [хороший скрипт](https://github.com/litejs/date-format-lite). это конечно модуль для npm, но `index.js` можно подключить к сайту и тоже будет работать*

и на сервере (`$link` – объект, который вы получили из функции `mysqli_connect`)

```
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['postVar']);
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date=$date");
```

а ещё лучше так:

```
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['postVar']);
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')=$date");
```

потому что у вас всё равно в часах, минутах и секундах нули. лучше выберите тип `date` вместо `timestamp`

[вот тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5dc42f/3) можно поиграться

*кстати, третья выборка тоже работает*

**UPD:** экранирование

Comment: Дата формируется при клике на один из день календаря,этот день мне и нужно получить

Comment: Рекомендую в примерах сразу показывать, что данные запроса необходимо экранировать

Comment: Функция `new Date(...)` создаёт новый объект даты. Я не знаю что в вашей программе  передается в функцию, но даже если это – указанная вами строка (`"Thu Nov 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT 0500 (RTZ 4 (Зима))"` тип `string`), функция `new Date(start)` правильно создаст объекти даты и позволит с ним работать – можете поиграться в консоли вашего браузера.

Comment: Также добавил в пример экранирование